# Enqueue controller action process

Tags: symfony, symfony-process, pheanstalk, php-enqueue

Symfony 2.8

Using https://github.com/j-guyon/CommandSchedulerBundle to manage periodic Command executions.

Each of these Command executions invokes an specific Service based on the Command arguments.

Being in the Services (all of them implementing the same Interface and extending an Abstract class), the plan is to create and execute sub-processes (asynchronously if possible)

Based in your experience, which will be the best way to deal with that sub-processes?

- Create a Process object (based on a Controller Action) for each sub-process, and run them synchronously (https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/process.html)
- Use kind of Queue Bundle to deal with all of them (Process or Messages or whatever), such https://php-enqueue.github.io/symfony  or https://github.com/armetiz/LeezyPheanstalkBundle  (any other suggestion?)

Cheers!

Comment: Running subprocesses in PHP is not best idea to go. I think using a queue with separated consumers is the best option. It's also will decouple your code. Look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check out some option that fits our symfony 2.8. Cheers!